# Generating addresses starting with certain characters such as "JoeAnonymousUserB7pMqyVa8JRcpZdCQLQ"

Tags: address, vanity-address

Similar to how the SHA256 hash competition exists to validate a transaction, I wonder if this concept can be ported to addresses, so that the first few characters is significant to a human reader.

- Is there value in making a public key address start with human readable text?
- What approaches exist to accomplish this?  Must the key pair be re-generated continuously or there there space to place a nonce?
- Could this cause legal issues?  ...such as a key that contains text matching censored information which is replicated to countries that ban that information

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the concept is known, and called "[vanity address](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3139/how-can-i-generate-a-vanity-bitcoin-address)". The problem with it is that it takes a lot of computing power. However, there is also a ["split-key" method of generating vanity addresses](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3853/can-one-safely-buy-vanity-addresses-from-a-third-party-without-risking-ones-coi), which lets you commission other people for the computing work. And finally, I created a website called [Vanity Pool](https://vanitypool.appspot.com/) that handles a sort of free market of vanity miners and buyers.

As for the legal issues, I have already included a so called ["illegal number"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3444/has-any-illegal-data-been-saved-in-the-block-chain) in the block chain as a part of my [master thesis](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=88149.0). So far Bitcoin hasn't been banned;).

Comment: Yes, that part of the question was inspired from your master thesis.  Great work, highly recommended reading!